# Aptana / Titanium Studio Disable Highlighting

Tags: titanium, aptana

Aptana/Titanium Studio is a pretty good IDE, but the preferences are a mess.

I want to basically turn off all the annoying highlighting and code hints it bombards you with but can't find the preferences for that.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [update] - I found the answer. If you go to Preferences and under Editors you need to uncheck "Mark occurrences with background color" under each document type.

Answer (score 0):

You can click the "Mark Occurrences" button in the toolbar, and that should toggle it for all Aptana editors.